# Installing a Matlab App in MATLAB R2012a

Tags: matlab, installation

First off I'm not a regular Matlab user, so this might appear as a rather simple question, but how do you install Apps in Matlab R2012a?  Is it even possible?  I found a link for how to do it in R2012b [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/discovery/matlab-apps.html), but I can't find any guidelines on how to do it in R2012a.

I have a custom app that was sent to me by a colleague at another research institution, and I think they must have a more recent version of Matlab that us.  His instructions were to go to the Apps tab in the tool bar and select Install Apps, but in R2012a, I can only see File, Edit, Debug, Parrallel, Desktop, Window and Help.  I've also had a look in the Product Help guide in Matlab, but I couldn't find a relevant entry.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe MATLAB apps were introduced in R2012b, and that it's not possible to install or use them in earlier releases. You would need to contact your colleague, and ask them to supply an unpackaged version of the application (i.e. just the code).

Comment: I've just had another trawl through the Matlab website, and indeed you're absolutely right.  Apps aren't compatible with R2012a.  Thanks for the quick response.